# One line of code in Loop gives undesirable results

Tags: loops, ms-access, vba

The code below copies the values of the selected record to all records on my form.

But, this line in the code is giving me undesirable results

```
.Fields("ResultsID").Value = Me.TestResultID.Value
```

Instead of copying the TestResultIDs of each record into ResultsID, it makes all ResultsID the same as the selected record's TestResultsID.

Where would be the best place to move that line of code to?

```
With Me.RecordsetClone
.MoveFirst
Do While .EOF = False
If .Fields("[Ordered Analyte]").Value = Me.[Ordered Analyte].Value Then
.Edit
    .Fields("DateStarted").Value = Me.DateStarted.Value
    .Fields("TimeStarted").Value = Me.TimeStarted.Value
    .Fields("DateCompleted").Value = Me.DateCompleted.Value
    .Fields("TimeCompleted").Value = Me.TimeCompleted.Value
    .Fields("Result").Value = Me.Result.Value
    .Fields("Count").Value = Me.[txtCount].Value
    .Fields("ResultsID").Value = Me.TestResultID.Value
.Update
End If
.MoveNext
Loop
End With
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you're moving the records in the form at all, just the clone, so you keep assigning the same value.  Why not create two recordsets, and nest your do loops so you loop through each record.  Or use your Do-Loop and use the findrecord method to get your match instead of the IF statement.

Comment: @geeFlo I'm sorry but that went right over my head

Comment: Look up "Nested Loops" as your answer might be there, and you might want to create two distinct recordsets - one reads, one writes.  Never really use recordsetclones as I thought they were read only, but it looks like your code is only ever writing one record (where [Ordered Analyte] = itself).   Are you calling this with another procedure?

Comment: in english: the code starts with `With Me.RecordsetClone` which means all of the records are duplicated. if Me is a form, all of the records in the form make up one recordset, and that recordset is duplicated, or cloned. so it looks like you're comparing the original recordset with an exact duplicate. if somehow the code seems to be working, something else is going on that we can't see. maybe problem with ResultsID is that it's an autonumber and can't be updated?

Comment: what kind of control is Me.TestResultID? a textbox, combobox?

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
.Fields("ResultsID").Value = Me.TestResultID.Value
```

with

```
.Fields("ResultsID").Value = .Fields("TestResultsID").Value
```

to use the TestResultsID from each individual record instead of just the current one.

Comment: that throws a Run-Time error 3265, Item not found in this collection.

Comment: what is the exact name of your "TestResultID"  field in the table? That is what you should use inside the last set of quotes where I have "TestResultsID".

Answer (score 0):

> The code below copies the values of the selected record to all records
>   on my form.

and:

> it makes all ResultsID the same as the selected record's TestResultsID.

Thus, your code works *exactly as intended*.